# Relative import paths need explicit file extensions in EcmaScript imports when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext'. Did you mean './*.js'

Tags: node.js, typescript

In package.json I have `"type": "module"` and I use SWC to compile the typescript code.  When doing imports I use `import Example from './example'` and then use `"start": "node --es-module-specifier-resolution=node lib/index.js"` as a script so that I don't have to specify the extensions.  This allows me to compile using SWC without needing to specify the extensions which is amazing, otherwise I have to specify .js extensions, inside typescript, for when it's compiled to a different /lib directory.

However when running `tsc --emitDeclrationOnly` on the codebase it breaks with the above error when I have `"moduleResolution": "nodenext"` in tsconfig.json.  It's telling me that nodenext or node16 enforces file extensions.  That is quite annoying and sort of makes it difficult to use nodenext or node16.  Is there a reason why this is done, or am I missing something that allows me to easily tell typescript how to resolve extensions by itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node requires file extension for import statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65873101/node-requires-file-extension-for-import-statement)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49083 \ seems its a must, though I prefer not to add any file extension.

Answer (score 2):

in tsconfig.json
use     "moduleResolution": "Bundler",

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

add param `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node`

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/esm.html#customizing-esm-specifier-resolution-algorithm

Comment: please double check that the edit is correct

Answer (score -3):

See slebetman's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65874173/132510. Try appending '.js' to the filename in the `import` statement, or make it an absolute import.